# How do I upload css and js files to my magento site through the admin console?

Tags: upload

Is there a way to upload `css` and `js` files to the the site's `/css` and `/js` folders through the Admin Console? Currently, the only way I envision this possible is through gaining `ftp` access to the website.

Answer (score 1):

If your `css/js` is very short then I would say yes, you can add in admin area.

Go to `System > Configuration > Design > Footer` then add your code like this in `Miscellaneous HTML` box:

```
<style>
   your css
</style>

<script>
   your js snippet
</script>
```

However, if you have got very large css/js files like you said, then I would suggest, you should add as a file from ftp. There is no other way to upload files from admin area in native magento.

Comment: I don't see System > Configuration... could this mean that I don't have enough permissions to the Admin Console?

Comment: Yes, that could be the case.

Comment: Or you are on Magento 2, where the configuration is in "Stores", not in "System", as in Magento 1.

Comment: According to http://magentoversion.com/ I am on v1.9.2.4. I'll ask for more permissions and see if that helps. Thanks!